# Selenium Webdriver - GeckoDriver - INFO: Detected dialect: W3C Error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm getting the below error when i try to perform sample search on google

> 1486404621556 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:20799
>
> Feb 06, 2017 11:10:22 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession
>
> INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true
>   on the remote end
>
> 1486404622116 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
>
> 1486404622117 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on
>   localhost:54870
>
> 1486404623314 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54870
>
> Feb 06, 2017 11:10:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession
>
> **INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException     at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)  at
>   TestGoogleSearch.main(TestGoogleSearch.java:24)**

The commands executed are below :

```
import    org.openqa.selenium.By;
import     org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import     org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import     org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import     org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestGoogleSearch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\javeed\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";

    String actualTitle = "";

    // launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    // get the actual value of the title
   actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

    driver.wait(5000);

    WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    wb.sendKeys("test");

     //close Firefox
    driver.close();

    // exit the program explicitly
    System.exit(0);


}

}
```

As soon it launches the google website and before it types anything in search, I get the above error as mentioned above

**Installed Jars/Software :**

```
     1. jdk-8u111-windows-x64

     2. selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1

     3. geckodriver

     4. Version: Kepler Service Release 1

    5. Build id: 20130919-0819

    6. Firefox Version : 51.0.1(32 bit)
```

Comment: It worked for me with fireFox 60.0.2 and geckodriver V0.20.1, after removing the wait time.

Comment: I have tried with thread. sleep too but , getting the same error. It's coming only in Internet Explorer for other browsers it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is an [IllegalMonitorStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) which is:

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

This was caused by your code `driver.wait(5000);`

Try changing it to `Thread.sleep(5000);`

Do keep in mind that using Sleep() is not preffered and you should instead wait for a condition. Example from [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```